# Intro.Js Cant Run On Php

Tags: javascript

So I want to make this button i took from intro.js to work  on PHP so that this button can run a function

```
     <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" id="belajarr">Tutorial</a>
```

The Scripts are

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#belajarr').on('click', function(){  
   href("javascript:void(0);"),
   onclick("javascript:introJs().setOption('showProgress', true).start();")
});
}); 
</script>
```

I Dont know how to make the javascript:introJs run because i take this intro js from this example of intro js and download it 
https://introjs.com/example/hello-world/index.html
I tried to make an alert when the button is pressed well its worked except the href and onclick function , i dont really understands how the laravel php works .

UPDATE: 
Because many of you still confused about what im asking , here's the point 
What im trying to ask is 
How to implement this HTML code

```
<a class="btn btn-large btn-success"  href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:introJs().setOption('showProgress', true).start();">Show me how</a>
```

to a PHP laravel blade framework which cant accept Javascript as i know and we had to write this using ajax as i doing here

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#belajarr').on('click', function(){  
   href("javascript:void(0);"),
   onclick("javascript:introJs().setOption('showProgress', true).start();")
});
}); 
</script>
```

I dont know if its right , but as far as i know when i gave it an alert it shows when i press the button . but it didnt run the function javascript:introJs()

Comment: PHP is irrelevant, and your code bears no resemblance to the demo you link to.

Comment: Hi there , sorry for the lacks of information i gave. The only thing i need is how to run javascript onclick on php , i tried to use the Ajax but still no results

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant. It just generates HTML. Follow the instructions given on introjs.com (what you have looks like utter nonsense).

Answer (score -1):

Ryan  i think that your are confusing the server part PHP whit  client part (JS, HTMl , CSS)  your question is about how . execute intro.js library in client no in server .

For do  this i think that this  does can work .

```js
     $('#belajarr').on('click', function(){   
        introJs(".aaa").start();
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://introjs.com/minified/introjs.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://introjs.com/minified/intro.min.js"></script>
     <button class="btn btn-large btn-success" id="belajarr">Tutorial</button>
     <div class='aaa' style='height: 100px;width: 100px; background-color:red'></div>
```